# How can I parallel parsing in python?

Tags: python, graph, io, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have the following code which converts graph from edges list to adjacency matrix:

```
for line in open('graph.txt'):
    converted = [sparse_to_dense.get(int(ID)) for ID in line.split()]
    i = converted[0]
    j = converted[1]
    I.append(i)
    J.append(j)
n = max([max(I), max(J)]) + 1
data = [1]*len(I)
return coo_matrix((data, (I,J)), shape=(n,n), dtype='i1')
```

This code is awfully slow -- on may machine conversion of 500k edges takes hours. On the other hand i/o is obviously is not bottleneck (I can read full file in memory almost instantaneously) so I think there is a room for parallelism. But I'm not sure how to proceed: should I read file in parallel or something?

Comment: [Why not look into threading?](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: @heinst I may be wrong but threading solves problem when IO is a bottle neck and most of the time program waits for IO. In my case program eats 100% of one cpu and io is negligible here.

Comment: I guess you care about the order in which you appent to I and J. correct?

Comment: @gosom not really. I'm reading I(i) and J(j) from the same line and I need them being synchronized, but order does not matter. I need something like the multiprocessing's workers with persistent state. So I would concatenate results from different workers in the end.

Comment: you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool with apply_async and some callback to get your results in as they come

Comment: Which part of this is actually slow? Reading the file and building `I`/`J`, or the call to `coo_matrix`? If the majority of the time is spent in `coo_matrix`, there really isn't anything `multiprocessing` can do to help you.

Comment: @dano you are absolutely right, I need to profile it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiprocessing one way to do it is this. I did not check and could be further improved

```
import multiprocessing


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue, results):
         multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self):
         self.q = queue
         self.results = results

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                lineno, linecontents = self.q.get(block=False)
            except Queue.Empty:
                break
            converted = [sparse_to_dense.get(int(ID)) for ID in line.split()]
             i = converted[0]
             j = converted[1]
            self.results.put((i, j))


def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    results = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

    for i, l in open(fname):
        q.put((i, l))

    for _ in xrange(4):
        w = Worker(q, results)
        w.start()

    I, J = []
    while True:
        try:
            i, j = results.get(block=False)
        except Queue.Empty:
        break
    I.append(i)
    J.append(j)
    results.task_done()

    results.join()

    n = max([max(I), max(J)]) + 1
    data = [1]*len(I)
    coo = coo_matrix((data, (I,J)), shape=(n,n), dtype='i1')
```

Comment: `results.get()` will never raise a `Queue.Empty` exception. It will block when the `results` is empty. You need to use `get_nowait()` instead. Your indentation in `main` also seems off.